# Date Filtering Malfunction in Powerview

Tags: multidimensional-array, sharepoint-2013, ssas, powerview

I am building a reporting solution using Powerview on Sharepoint Server 2013 with ssas multidimensional data source.

On the powerview reports I have encountered a strange problem. When I filter using a date attribute with multiple values only the non calculated facts (simple measures, not mdx) are being filtered, while for single date selection everything is filtered correctly.

The strange thing is that in the cube browser everything works fine for all facts and all dates selections.

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Sample Calculations :

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.Measures.NewRequestsCount
as

aggregate({[DM RMS Workflow Actions].[Standard Action FK].&[13],[DM RMS Workflow Actions].[Standard Action FK].&[1]},[Measures].[FC RMS Request Actions Count]),
ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP='FC RMS Request Actions',format_string="#,##0";
```

and

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.Measures.ForwardsCount
as

aggregate(([DM RMS Workflow Actions].[SN].&[62],[DM RMS Is Fake].[Value].&[Real]),[Measures].[FC RMS Request Actions Count]),
ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP='FC RMS Request Actions',format_string="#,##0";
```

Comment: Can you include a sample calc which isn't working?

Comment: Yes of course, thanks

Comment: I just noticed that the behavior is the same for every filter not only the date filters. If I choose multiple values then the calculation is shown for all values.

Comment: What is the calculation behind [Measures].[FC RMS Request Actions Count]? Or if it's a physical measure what's the AggregateFunction? If you change Aggregate() to Sum() do you have the same problem?

Comment: It is the default count of the measure group. Nothing changes if I use sum. The filters work fine in excel pivot tables also...It must be a Power View related problem

Comment: If you comment out the entire MDX script except for the CALCULATE statement and use a physical measure in your report does the multiselect work? I'm wondering if your MDX Script has a scope statement that's causing problems.

Comment: Yes the multiselect works. I have encountered problems in the scope on the past but they were happening both in Power View and Cube Browser. Now the problem happens only in Power View :/

Comment: So what's the problem SCOPE statement?

Comment: It was in a different project than the current in which I am having the problem. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: So you are saying that a physical measure works for multiselect but any calculated measure does not work? Even if the calculated measure is Measure*2 or something simple?

Comment: Yes exactly! Even for the simplest calculated measure...(tested with measure-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

The problem was solved by installing Sql Server 2012 sp3

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49996.

Comment: Great news! What version were you on before?

Comment: Yes it was a relief, thank you. I was on Sql Server 2012 sp2